# VB.NET System32 Path

Tags: vb.net, dir, system32

I'm trying to copy a file to System32 folder. I tried;

```
System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%\system32")

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
```

It didn't work. It always returns to C:/Windows . What should i do to get System32 folder ? Thanks.

Comment: Both ways should work. Are you sure the error is not elsewhere?

Comment: I'm using it like that. I added my code in the thread.

Comment: Don't write to System32. Bad code monkey. No cookie.

Comment: Are you really trying to write in the C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 and replace the content of msvcr100d.dll?

Comment: LOL. I have to copy the msvcr100d and msvcp100d .dll files in System32 folder, else it gives missing msvcr100d and msvcp100d errors. q.q

Comment: Well, you should use the debugger and check the variables `fff`, `ff1` etc. Then you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many security/antivirus warnings you need to accept before?

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` rather than `+` to add the file names to the path.  And also, I agree with everyone else, this really is shockingly horrendous.  If I could think of a worse way to describe it, I would.

Comment: There are established ways to deploy the C run time libraries. This isn't it. Not even close.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those work. You can verify you have the proper directory by setting a breakpoint on line 2 of your `Button1_Click` method and then inspecting the value of `dir`.

That being said, you really shouldn't be writing to the System32 folder (or really anything from the Windows folder down, with the exception of Temp). If you're trying to install an application on the end-user machine, you should be using an installer (and writing to the Program Files folder) instead.

Writing directly into the System32 folder isn't normally allowed (unless you've turned off access control and a lot of security features) as it introduces a huge security risk. You're also not guaranteed that it will even work on all systems because of different security controls that may (or may not) be in place.

Comment: Dim dir As String =     System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%\System32\System32")    this worked, ty anyway.. :/